# How to convert array of objects in one specific object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

So, I had the very tiny, but hard for me task from my last interview. I just itreseted in how to solve it. I think that we need to implement the recursion in this task, but I do not know it clearly.

The task:

```
let arr = [{name: 'width', value: 300}, {name: 'height', value: 100}];
```

On output we must have:

```
let obj = {width:300, height: 100};
```

The count of array objects can be infinity.

P.S.
I'll be pleased if you provide me with link on knowleges to how make this task done.

Thank you.

Comment: OP, my answer below keeps height/width paired like you wanted for each object. Let me know if you need more help with that. Have you tried any other answers here yet?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative using the function `reduce`

#### Brief explanation

- The function `Array.prototype.reduce` loops an array applying a handler for each object.
- The accumulator `a` will contain the result from each iteration.
- The function `converter` receives the accumulator and the current object.
- This `Object.assign(a, {[name]: value})` assigns a new property to the current accumulator.
- **Computed property names** `{[name]: value}` that code will build an object as follow:

```
{ width: 300 }
```

```js
let arr = [{name: 'width', value: 300},{name: 'height', value: 100}],
    converter = (a, {name, value}) => (Object.assign(a, {[name]: value})),
    obj = arr.reduce(converter, {});

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good code, but doesn't this make it so width and height would be on their own? I believe OP wants width and height paired, so it's two objects from original array being combined. So that original array length should be double the length of final output. I believe OPs desired output is one object with height and width PER PAIR in the original array.

Comment: @Nerdi.org the answer follows the OP's requirements.

Comment: But that's what I'm getting at... OP has an array of unlimited objects. The expected outcome is that pairs of width/height dimensions (from 2 objects in original array) are grouped together in a single object. Those are the requirements, and as far as I can tell most of the answers here completely disregard that he wants values paired together, not listed as individual objects. If I'm misunderstanding how your code accomplishes that, I apologize - I'm just trying to clarify because there's a lot of answers here that simply don't result in the outcome OP wants.

Comment: But if I misunderstood it, I apologize. OP never stated really whether he's pairing height/width or if he wants every possible array name/value to be in a single object.

Comment: @Nerdi.org but, the input is an array.  The OP only wants to build a big Object with the nested objects from that array.

Comment: If that's true, then that's fine. All I'm saying is this: OPs code shows 1 of 2 desires: he either wants width/height to be paired in a single object, or he wants 100% of array values grouped in a single object. But because his expected output supports both, it's actually hard to tell - especially because width/height pairings makes a lot of sense especially if this is a case of having to reformat previously bad-formatted data (unpaired height/width in array for examlple). You're probably right, so I added a for loop to my answer to accomplish your understanding of question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work for infinity pairs of `obj` inside the `arr`. For example `let arrr = [{name: 'width', value: 300},{name: 'height', value: 100},{name: 'width', value: 300},{name: 'height', value: 100}],
    converter = (a, {name, value}) => (Object.assign(a, {[name]: value})),
    obj = arrr.reduce(converter, {});

console.log(obj);` - will provide us with `Error`

Comment: @MaxWolfen can you explain what's the error you're facing?

Comment: @Ele just start the code example above that I post in comment and you  will see it. - The second pair of objects inside the `arr` (I mean `[2-3]`) provide us with `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

The array `.reduce` method would be a good fit. Start with an empty object and for each array item, add an entry to the object with that key and value. Example:

```js
let arr = [{name: 'width', value: 300}, {name: 'height', value: 100}];

let result = arr.reduce((combo, item) => {
    combo[item.name] = item.value;
    return combo;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing a comma between your two objects in the array :)

Whenever you're looking to process an array and come up with a single value, you're looking to use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). You can choose the direction (reduce or reduceRight) and the accumulator function, to produce the value (or object) desired.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using reduce, destructurization and object spread operator:

```js
const src = [{
  name: 'width',
  value: 300
}, {
  name: 'height',
  value: 100
}]

const reducer = (acc, { name, value }) => ({
  ...acc,
  ...{ [name]: value }
});


const out = src.reduce(reducer, {});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object by adding the key value pairs in the array, with the help of the bracket notations :

```js
let arr = [{name: 'width', value: 300},{name: 'height', value: 100}];
 let obj = {};
 arr.forEach(pair => obj[pair.name] = pair.value)
 console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = arr.length, 

var newA = []; 
let width, height, item; 
for(var x = 0; x < len; x+=2){ //add 2 for pair loop because width/height in diff array objects 
 item.width = arr[x].value;
 item.height = arr[x+1].value; 
 newA.push(item); 
 // newA = [{width:value, height:value}, {width:value, height:value}];
}
console.log(newA);
```

This should work for grouping width and height together in your final array :)

If you want just one big object (make sure there are no name duplicates !)...

```
var len = arr.length, 
obj = {}; 
for(var x = 0; x < len; x++){ 
 obj[arr[x].name] = arr[x].value;
} 
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach() to solve it as well.

```
let arr = [{name: 'width', value: 300},{name: 'height', value: 100}];
let obj = {};
arr.forEach(val=>obj[val.name]=val.value);
```

Comment: for() would be faster though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of objects in the form of `{ [name]: value }`, and merge them to a single object by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const arr = [{name: 'width', value: 300}, {name: 'height', value: 100}];

const object = Object.assign(...arr.map(({ name, value }) => ({ [name]: value })));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this with just a for loop:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    obj[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
}
```